# SQL Server DB Sync with Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have DB in my SQL Server. I want to replicate the same DB with all the Views inside it into Azure and sync the same SQL Server DB with replicated DB on Azure on daily basis.

I have no idea about Azure.

Comment: Then please find the tutorials on the google. There is no better learning than self learning. If you come across some issues during your learning, we would be glad to help.

Comment: Transactional Replication will give you one-way sync to Azure SQL Database.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-to-sql-database?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate a SQL Server 2005 or later database to a single or pooled database in Azure SQL Database. For best performance during the import process, it’s better to drop indexed views and recreate them once finished. For more details, you may refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate.

You can set up Azure SQL Data Sync by creating a hybrid sync group that contains both Azure SQL Database and SQL Server instances. For more details on how to achieve this, you may refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync.

**Note: Does SQL Data Sync fully create and provision tables?**
Views and Stored Procedures are not created on the destination database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Data Sync to sync the base tables of your views but SQL Data Sync cannot sync views. Sync data from views is quite complex and not always achievable and for that reason SQL Data Sync does not do it.

Use the step-by-step procedure described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) to configure the synchronization. You need to make your SQL Server instance a "hub", your SQL Azure Database a "member" on the sync configuration. Configure the "Sync frequency" parameter/field to occur every X days or X hours.